Leaning Mixture Methods
I just started my PPL training. I was going through the procedures of leaning the mixture during cruise and found that different instructors use different methods.
My instructor asked me to lean the mixture using RPM method where she asked me to keep leaning the mixture till the till the RPM starts to increase to its peak and then stop as soon as it starts decreasing.
Example - if RPM goes from 2000 -> 2100 while leaning and then 2100 -> 2080, stop leaning and make the RPM 2100 for best results.
Meanwhile I have heard other instructors use EGT method which I am not sure of.
Can someone point out the differences and what is the actual reason behind both methods.
I train on the Piper Archer PA28-181 G1000
Thanks.

You are missing one. There is also leaning to fuel flow rate.

Leaning by exhaust gas temperature really only works with fuel injected engines, and you ideally want an exhaust gas temperature indication for every cylinder although it can be done with a single cylinder gauge. You normally EGT lean to the lean side of peak temperature, say 50-75 deg lean of peak, depending on the engine. With fuel injected engines, the mixture distribution to the cylinders is relatively even.
With a carbureted engine the mixture distribution is less even and one cylinder will reach peak EGT before the others and the EGT method is less effective.
You will notice the difference right away when you fly an injected engine. If you over lean, the carbureted engine starts to run rough as the first cylinder gets too lean to fire, while the others carry on as normal. The injected engine will generally just quit, as all 4 cylinders hit the over lean point at once (assuming the fuel distributor is working properly).
Leaning a carbureted engine can be done by leaning to best power (peak rpm) and enriching slightly. Best power will produce the highest cylinder head temperature and I personally don't recommend it for cruise. A bit rich of best power is better. Another method is to just lean to roughness, and enrich a bit (it's what I normally do).

The EGT method requires an EGT gauge, which not all training planes possess. The older the plane, the less likely it is to have one.
